# including .php file from different folder (Back folder)

Tags: php, html, include

If it is in same folder or root folder

```
<?php include "head.php" ?>
```

if it is in inc `(Forward)` folder

```
<?php include "inc/head.php" ?>
```

If it is in back folder

**Now :**

The file i want to edit located in `root -> blog -> articles -> article.php`

I want to include head from `root --> inc --> head.php`

How to write a code to include `head.php` in `article.php` .

```
<?php include ("$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']"."/inc/head.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Try `../../inc/head.php`. Why do you use /common in your attempt when you said the file is in /inc?

Comment: `../../inc/head.php` not working. i misspelled inc with common. previous my folder name was common then i changed to inc. it just a typo confusion.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What exact error do you get?

Comment: `head.php` file from `inc` folder is not included in `article.php` with code `../../inc/head.php`

Comment: Use `require` rather than `include` and it'll generate an error if it fails. Make sure PHP error reporting is switched on.

Comment: @ADyson your code is working. my bad. head.php have code like `<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />` so it is 404.